# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'

Tags: android

I am trying to use Google Maps on my Android App. I installed the Google play services and I acquired the API key. I don't understand why I am getting this error message! I think its complaining about the following.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Error Message:

```
  Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
       > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
             file:/C:/Users/Ammar/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
             file:/C:/Users/Ammar/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
             file:/C:/Users/Ammar/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
             file:/C:/Users/Ammar/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
         Required by:
             Client:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3
       > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
             file:/C:/Users/Ammar/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
             file:/C:/Users/Ammar/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
             file:/C:/Users/Ammar/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
             file:/C:/Users/Ammar/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
         Required by:
             Client:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0
```

Comment: the problem is with your gradle.build please post that

Comment: you need to update your support library..please post the gradle.build if you want the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously it is looking for v4 (com.android.support:support-v4) jar. Do you have it in your build path?

For android studio, in your gradle file in `dependencies` block,  add following line-

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.+'
    // your other dependencies as well

}
```

And make sure you have downloaded the Android support library by SDK manager. If you didn't already, refer to official documentation [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Comment: I don't think so, how do I add it?

Comment: what are you using android studio or eclipse?