# How to tackle the following error?

Tags: android, sdk, build.gradle

Is it something to change in my project gradle, or do I have to update my sdk?

problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0.

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

```
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:\_debugCompile'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580487/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-app-debugcompile)

Comment: he had problem with API. that doesn't have helped me

Comment: If possible then please upload your app level gradle file code so we can find  Exect solution

Comment: show your build,gradle (module level) file.